# celery task is assigning local instance attributes in subsequent tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a task that creates a task history record every time a new task is processed. I instantiate a new TaskHistory instance at the beginning of the task function. For some reason TaskHistory class attributes assigned in a previous task are being assigned to TaskHistory class attributes in subsequent tasks. For example, if the task succeeds I assign:

```
 task_history.meta['success'] = 'Successfully processed {} rows '.format(row_count)'
```

In a subsequent task it might fail and I assign:

```
task_history.meta['error'] = 'Processed {} rows '.format(row_count) + str(e)
```

The subsequent task should only assign meta['error'] but it's assigning the previous meta['success'] value as well even though the task_history was reinstantiated.

Below is the code that calls the task:

```
args = [file_ids]
kwargs = {'requester': request.user.profile}
csv_import.apply_async(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

Below is the task function:

```
@task
def csv_import(file_ids, requester=None):
    task_history = TaskHistory()
    task_history.requester = requester
    task_history.status = 'pending'
    task_history.started = timezone.now()
    task_history.save()
    row_count = 0
    try:

       //main logic goes here

       task_history.status = 'completed'
       task_history.completed = now()
       task_history.meta['success'] = 'Successfully processed {} rows '.format(row_count)
       task_history.save()
    except Exception as e:
        task_history.status = 'failed'
        task_history.completed = timezone.now()
        task_history.meta['error'] = 'Processed {} rows '.format(row_count) + str(e)
        task_history.save()
        raise Exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this had nothing to do with celery but with the way I set the default value for my meta field in my model. The meta field is a **JSONfield()** and I set the default value to **default={}** which creates a mutable instance and is shared between all instances of JSONfield. I fixed this by setting it to a callable **dict**. The new field now appears as followed:

```
meta = JSONField(default=dict)
```

More information about this can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield. This is the same standard that should be used for all model default values.